# Нужна функция, переводящая дату в количество суток

Tags: c++

Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает 3 значения типа int (день, месяц, год), потом переводит дату в количество суток, а потом возвращает количество суток. Знаю как без функций написать, но может какие функции есть?

```
int date_day(int day,int month,int year)
{
    //КОД
    return day_;
}
```

Comment: И что такое количество суток для 27 апреля 2020 года?

Comment: это года умножить на 365, 366 + месяц по счету умножить на 30,31 + день в месяце, ну просто возиться с 365,366 и 30,31 не хочется, там же столетия вроде не считаются как високосные года)

Comment: С какого момента? От 1970 года? От рождества христова? От вымирания динозавров?

Comment: Можно начиная с начала нашей эры, а можно с 1970 года (но с динозаврами вы здорово придумали)

Comment: А вы знаете что такое unixtime и сколько секунд в сутках?

Comment: что такое unixtime знаю, но вот как это вычислить? Сколько секунд в сутках не считал)

Comment: Смотрите сюда - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Спасибо, получил, что хотел

Answer (score 2):

time() -это самая простая функция, которая выводит секунды [с начала Эпохи](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_15).

[На странице cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time), приведен этот пример :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
    std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result))
              << result << " seconds since the Epoch\n";
}
```

Comment: спасибо, не могли бы обьяснить вот этот момент?

`asctime(std::localtime(&result))`

Comment: Грустно, что ваша функция просто игнорит указываемую ТС дату `int date_day(int day,int month,int year)`, и возвращает только для текущего момента...